# Calling python from Actionscript

Tags: python, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an Adobe Air Program that calls a python script.  I dont' think the actionscript 3.0 is making the proper call. Code:

```
        var file:File;
        var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;

            file = new File().resolvePath("/usr/bin/python");

            var pyScript:File;
            pyScript = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("python/mac/merge.py");

            var tempOutPath:String = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("out.pdf").nativePath;
            args.push(pyScript.nativePath, "-w", "-o", tempOutPath, "-i");

            for(var x:int; x < numFilesToProcess; x++){

                var pdfPath:String = File(pdfs.getItemAt(x)).nativePath;

                args.push(pdfPath);

            }

            callNative(file, args);
```

In terminal (Mac), the following works fine:

```
python merge.py -w -o out.pdf -i file1.pdf file2.pdf
```

The args.push(pyScript.native.... line is the problematic one.  I'd appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced a similar problem using Air. I needed to print to a receipt printer from an Air app. I couldn't do it from the app itself so I used a python RPC server to do the work for me and talked to it over http. below is a simplified version to give you an idea:

The python RPC server

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/','/RPC2')

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 8123), requestHandler=RequestHandler)

def myService( arg0, arg1 ):
    #do the stuff
    return 0

server.register_function(myService)
server.serve_forever()
```

In Air I create the call as an XML string and make my request.
I haven't shown all the details as I was using javascript not actionscript so please treat this as pseudocode.

```
// XML as a string
// possibly create the XML and toXMLString() it?
var data:String = '
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>myService</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <string>file1.pdf</string>
        </param>
        <param>
            <string>file2.pdf</string>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>';

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('localhost:8123');
rec.method = 'POST';
rec.data = data;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader( req );
//etc
```