# How can I launch a python script using Adobe AIR's NativeProcess?

Tags: python, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I'm having more than a little trouble running a python script from an AIR application using the NativeProcess interface. In theory, this should be quite simple. Adobe even uses this as their example in the [ActionScript 3.0 documentation for NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html), as follows:

```
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("test.py");
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
```

They even include the contents of what test.py might include:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Sample Python script
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import sys

for word in sys.argv: #echo the command line arguments
    print word

print "HI FROM PYTHON"
print "Enter user name" 
line = sys.stdin.readline()

sys.stdout.write("hello," + line)
```

The problem is that, as far as I can see, this simply doesn't work. I get the following error when I attempt it:

```
Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. '%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Presumably the latest version of AIR (19.0) doesn't allow the execution of anything without an "exe" file extension. The following code does seem to do what I want:

```
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
var file:File = new File("C:/Python/Python35/python.exe");
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(".");

var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
processArgs[0] = "test.py";
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
```

The problem here is twofold. First, you need to know the absolute path to the executable, which I can't assume. Second, the code is no longer platform independent. The file extension would be something else on Linux or Mac.

I thought I might solve the first problem by requiring a %PYTHON_PATH% environment variable and then making the executable dependent on that. However, I can't figure out a way to use an environment variable within the ActionScript File object. It "helpfully" escapes all the "%" characters before ever sending something to the command line.

At this point this fairly simple problem has turned into a showstopper. Could someone help me understand a way to either:

1. Execute something with the "py" extension with NativeProcess
2. Successfully resolve a path that depends on an environment variable in the File object?

Comment: AFAIK there is no direct way to launch the python interpreter from AIR. There was an experimental project by Mike Chambers that allowed to launch processes in the operating system, but it's quite old: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/17/commandproxy-net-air-integration-proof-of-concept/ . Other than that, maybe you'll need to launch different executables based on the operation system ? You still can place all executables in your application directory and include them in the installation package

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505355/calling-python-from-actionscript looks like from a quick search someone got it working.

Comment: @quantomworks It might look that way, but Marlon never explains how his mythical "callNative" function works. I have no reason to believe he doesn't run into the above problems.

Comment: It's not mythical.. I remember running into the same type of problem when trying to run a java file... I'll be working soon on using ffmpeg for converting my videos..maybe then I can help out with this.

Comment: ...
Try launching cmd.exe in C:/windows/system32 and running the script that way by calling python through command line. What happens?